# Can't retrieve data in PHP API

Tags: php, rest, pdo

I'm building a simple CRUD app as a learning exercise in Angularjs and PHP.  I have a shell page, mysql backend, a PHP API that handles the SQL requests, and I'm using Angularjs to handle the flow of data between the shell page and the API. I'm working off an API modeled here:

http://angularcode.com/demo-of-a-simple-crud-restful-php-service-used-with-angularjs-and-mysql/

I've tested every component of this app so far and everything works cleanly except the API. All I've done to modify the original was change the syntax to PDO and I adjusted the response function because the existing one didn't work.

The abstract class:

```
<?php
class REST {

    public $_allow = array();
    public $_content_type = "application/json";
    public $_request = array();

    private $_method = "";      
    private $_code = 200;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->inputs();
    }

    public function get_referer(){
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }

    /*public function response($data,$status){
        $this->_code = ($status)?$status:200;
        $this->set_headers();
        echo $data;
        exit;
    }*/
    public function response($status, $status_message, $data){
    header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");
    $response['status'] = $status;
    $response['status_message'] = $status_message;
    $response['data'] = $data;

    $json_response = json_encode($response);

}
    private function get_status_message(){
        $status = array(
                    200 => 'OK',
                    201 => 'Created',  
                    204 => 'No Content',  
                    404 => 'Not Found',  
                    406 => 'Not Acceptable');
        return ($status[$this->_code])?$status[$this->_code]:$status[500];
    }

    public function get_request_method(){
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }

    private function inputs(){
        switch($this->get_request_method()){
            case "POST":
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_POST);
                break;
            case "GET":
            case "DELETE":
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_GET);
                break;
            case "PUT":
                parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$this->_request);
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($this->_request);
                break;
            default:
                $this->response('',406);
                break;
        }
    }       

    private function cleanInputs($data){
        $clean_input = array();
        if(is_array($data)){
            foreach($data as $k => $v){
                $clean_input[$k] = $this->cleanInputs($v);
            }
        }else{
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
                $data = trim(stripslashes($data));
            }
            $data = strip_tags($data);
            $clean_input = trim($data);
        }
        return $clean_input;
    }       

    private function set_headers(){
        header("HTTP/1.1 ".$this->_code." ".$this->get_status_message());
        header("Content-Type:".$this->_content_type);
    }
}   
?>
```

And the API itself:

```
<?php
require_once("Rest.inc.php");

class API extends REST {

    public $data = "";


    private $db = NULL;
    private $conn = NULL;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();              
        $this->dbConnect();             
    }

    /*
     *  Connect to Database
    */
    private function dbConnect(){
        $this->conn = null;

        $servername="myServer";
        $dbname="mySQL";
        $username="myUN";
        $password="myPW";

        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;Database=$dbname",$username, $password);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Failed:" . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
    /*
     * Dynmically call the method based on the query string
     */
    public function processApi(){
        //$func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['x']))); //<<--NEED TO FIX THIS.  x determines which function to call
        $func = 'quote';
        if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0){
            $this->$func();
        }else{
            $this->response(404,'',''); 
        }
    }

    private function quote(){   
        if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
            $this->response(406, '', '');
        }
        $id = (int)$this->_request['id'];
        if($id > 0){
            try{
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM mysql.Quotes WHERE ID =:ID";
                $query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
                $query->bindParam(":ID", $id);
                $query->execute();
                $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Failed:" . $e->getMessage();
            }

            echo $this->response(200,"Success",$result);    
        }
    }   

// Initiate Library

$api = new API;
$api->processApi();
?>
```

One issue I'm aware of is that the commented portion in processAPI() does not work.  It's supposed to grab the initial part of the URL and determine which function to run based on based on that, but my server keeps throwing an error.  My workaround for the time being is just to hard-code $func = 'quote';

More importantly, though, the API returns an empty object whenever it runs.  It connects to the DB and executes without errors, and it does return an object as designed -- there just isn't anything inside it.  If I pull out the core components -- the DB connection, the SQL request, and the response function -- and run them on their own, they correctly pull the data and pass it on to the shell.  So something in the REST class or the API must be fouling it up, but I'm not handy enough in PHP yet to figure out where it's going wrong.  I'd appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $func; exit();`? What is the output?

Comment: With the original code, where $func is defined by $_REQUEST['x'], it throws an error that x is undefined.  With that part commented out, it outputs "quote."

Comment: Does your url look like this: `/Rest.inc.php?x=foobar`? That's what it should be.

Comment: Yes, the URL is correct.

Comment: Have you tried changing `'x'` to `'func'`?

Comment: also try this: `print_r($_REQUEST); exit();`